# Micronaut custom validation Annotation does not work

Tags: bean-validation, micronaut

I was trying to write a custom annotation to validate a field in a Micronaut project, I came across this section in their documentation [Defining Additional Constraints](https://docs.micronaut.io/1.3.0.M2/guide/index.html#_defining_additional_constraints)

My understanding was that is completely possible to write my own annotation to validate a field in my POJO but after trying for hours, I can't get my validation to work, it simply does not get invoked, could it be I'm missing something fundamental about the way how Micronaut works?

*Annotation*

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = [])
annotation class FieldValidator(
    val message: String = "invalid format ({validatedValue})"
)
```

*Factory*

```
@Factory
class ValidatorFactory {

    @Singleton
    fun fieldPatternValidator(): ConstraintValidator<FieldValidator, CharSequence> {
        return ConstraintValidator { value, annotation, context ->
            context.messageTemplate("invalid format ({validatedValue}), should be test") 
            value == "test"
        }
    }
}
```

*Filter*

```
@Introspected
data class HelloWorldFilter(
    @FieldValidator
    val field: String?
)
```

*Controller*

```
@Controller("/hello")
open class HelloController() {

    @Get("{?filters*}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    open fun index(@Valid filters: HelloWorldFilter): String {
        return filters.toString()
    }
}
```

I have a small demo on [Github](https://github.com/ericsnx/micronaut-validator), to reproduce

1. run `./gradlew run`
2. call `http://localhost:8080/hello?field=abc` that expected behaviour should be bad request since the field is matching the desired value.

Comment: Since your demo doesn't have any test nor steps to reproduce the issue. Only thing that stands out is:
`@FieldValidator val field: String?` normally with Kotlin it is `@field:FieldValidator`.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I forgot to add the step, Is basically running the service and calling the hello world endpoint, I will add the steps tomorrow!

Comment: @ShingJo I tried this already does not seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your demo project, I changed your `HelloWorldFilter` class to

```kotlin
@Introspected
data class HelloWorldFilter(
    @field:FieldValidator
    val field: String?
)
```

Ran it, then:

```bash
curl "http://localhost:8080/hello?field=abc"
```

Output was as you expect:

```bash
{"message":"Bad Request","_embedded":{"errors":[{"message":"filters.field: invalid format (abc), should be test"}]},"_links":{"self":{"href":"/hello?field=abc","templated":false}}}
```

With:

```bash
curl "http://localhost:8080/hello?field=test"
```

Output:

```bash
HelloWorldFilter(field=test)
```

Comment: Interesting, it was working, I guess the version I had running locally did not have @Valid(I probably removed it because I thought it was not necessary), you are right it seems to `@field:FieldValidator` I will read about why I need to declare it like that for instance @NotNull works just fine, thanks!